# Get a list of modified firebase cloud functions names for my CICD pipelines

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I am trying to find a way where I'll be able to get the names of modified cloud functions names with respect to local functions. That way I'll be able to only deploy those functions which are modified in my CICD pipelines

For example, I have a function called `createUser` and `manageUser`. Now right now if I run `firebase deploy --only functions` it will deploy both of these functions but what if my changes were only in `manageUser`. I want to be able to detect it and output a command like this `firebase deploy --only "functions:manageUser"`

I tried searching but couldn't find a solution. There were options of using git and file changes but that will cause issues for me because there are many developers in my team deploying functions from their own branches.

Answer (score 0):

As of the latest Firebase version. Firebase CLI functions are not deployed if there is no change to any file in the functions directory. This is already mentioned here on this [Github merge](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/pull/5032).

You can maximize this by using the [codebases](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions#organize_functions_in_codebases) feature for more granular groupings when deploying or even using it on CICD pipelines.